# SOA modelling terminologies

Tags: soa

I am learning SOA for our new project. I want to know basic information on SOA modelling technologies. I saw lot many terminologies in internet like SoaML, BPMN, SOMF, SOMA, SOBA ... and confused when/where to use what modelling technology.
Please help me to identify exact technology to model our services.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

- SOAML - UML Profile (Modeling notation) for modeling SOA.
- BPMN - Modeling notation for for modeling business processes.
- SOMF - Methodology for designing SOA architectures. From Michael Bell. Supported by tools like Sparx Enterprise Architect
- SOMA - Methodology for designing SOA architectures. From IBM. Supported by RSA.

Haven't heard of SOBA.

Answer (score 0):

Model your services using the simplest tool you can, I use blocks and line drawings for the overview (service) level models and UML sequence diagrams for depicting internal orchestration.

The modelling language will not help you learn how to build SOA, experience of doing and following best practices will help.

Good luck and enjoy the journey